# Magento2 Search Issues

Tags: magento2, frontend, search

Using Magento 2.1.10

The search part of Magento 2 seems quite buggy. I have a product titled `"abc with xyz"`.

1. When I search `"abc"`, the product gets displayed but its pushed in between the collection, with several items appearing before it, which does not even have `"abc"` in their names. I researched and adjusted the search weights and i still get the same result, no effect at all.
2. When I search "abc lights", the result is similar to point 1
3. When I search "with", I do not see the product listed. Other products which are irrelevant gets displayed

How can i search the products by NAME only. I have tried disabling the searchable for all the other Attributes. in this case when i search "with", I get no result at all.

I have already tried changing the query clause to `"must"` instead of `"should"`, but it still does not work

If possible, can someone please let me know where can I find the query in the code for it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not answer your question in 100% but I can't recommend enough to use the elasticsearch.

It improves the quality of search for Magento 2.

There is a free extension you can use. You can find it here: https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to **Magento's default search** and want to search by **NAME** field only, then you must stop other attributes to appear in the search filter criteria.

To do this:

1. Go to **Stores** >> **Attributes** (**Product**).
2. Search for **Searchable** = **Yes** in the attributes grid.
3. Open all these attributes one by one (except the **Name** attribute) and set Use in Search to No under **Storefront Properties** tab.
4. After finishing the above step, **reindex** and flush Magento's cache.

Try searching the frontend now.

This solution worked for me in the last 3 websites.

Please share if you find any better solution.

Comment: I have tried that as well. And its works as expected. But it does not resolve the 3rd point, which is that a product with name "abc with xyz", when i search "with", the product does not appear.. but when i search "abc" it does.

Comment: It should work. I have just tried in the default installation of Magento with sample data. It is working fine here.

Comment: For example, if I search for **`Radiant Tee`**, it is showing the product **`Radiant Tee`** at first place and then the products with any of the parts of search criteria individually.

Comment: i'm checking with following step but its not working my side.